# Default parameters from Python in a C++ defined function?

Tags: c++, python

I've embedded Python in my C++ application, and I've created several C functions which can be called from Python.

To get the arguments, I'm currently doing:

```
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "zk", &param1, &param2))
  return NULL;
```

However, I want `param2` to be optional. How can I check for the two of them separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You don't.](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html)

> `|`
>
> > Indicates that the remaining arguments in the Python argument list are optional. The C variables corresponding to optional arguments should be initialized to their default value — when an optional argument is not specified, `PyArg_ParseTuple()` does not touch the contents of the corresponding C variable(s).

```
param2 = 42;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "z|k", &param1, &param2))
  return NULL;
```

Comment: Sweet, I'll accept your answer once the 2 minutes are up -- thanks for the fast response!